# Como utilizar o FreeAndNil neste caso?

Tags: delphi, formulário

Tenho a seguinte rotina que destrói os formulários esquecidos abertos pelo usuário:

```
...    
        for i := qtd - 1 downto 0 do
        begin
                if (Application.components[i] is TForm) then
                begin
                    TForm(Application.components[i]).Close;
                    *** AQUI A NECESSIDADE DO *** 
                    FreeAndNil(Application.components[i]);
                end;
        end;
```

Vejam que preciso finalizar os formulários com FreeAndNil mas não estou conseguindo passar a referida variável, pois ali exige uma TObject no caso a Unit/Form a ser liberada.

Comment: `Application.components[i].Destroy` não resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Se não possui nada programado no `OnClose` não é necessário aciona-lo, para este caso, claro.

```
    for i := qtd - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if (Application.components[i] is TForm) then
      begin
        {Você testou se ele é um TForm, e a resposta foi positiva, então 
         teste qualquer um dos métodos a seguir}  

        TForm(Application.components[i]).Free;
        TForm(Application.components[i]).DisposeOf;
        TForm(Application.components[i]).Destroy; {citado corretamente pelo @Roberto de Campos}
        FreeAndNil(TForm(Application.components[i]));
      end;
    end;
```

Vale lembrar que não é uma boa pratica realizar este tipo de tratamento.
O correto para tratamento de formulários seria:

```
1 - Cria o Formulário
2 - Exibe ele
3 - Destrói ele
```

O Delphi é Horrível no gerenciamento de memória, se você alocou algo e não destruiu confiando que na destruição do formulário vai limpar, esta enganado!

Comment: Sim eu faço a sequencia que me passou, mas minha aplicação permite abrir varios formularios distintos, então as vezes o usuario vai em fechar no form principal, ai ja viu né